# Extracting cURL API in android Java

Tags: java, android, curl

I am trying to extract data from the EatStreet API using the following cURL command:

curl -X GET \
 -H 'X-Access-Token: **API_EXPLORER_AUTH_KEY**' \
 'https://api.eatstreet.com/publicapi/v1/restaurant/search?latitude=40.4310&longitude=-86.9149&method=both'

The code that I have written so far is as follows:

```
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.lang.StringBuffer;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        blah();
    }

    private static void blah() {
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();

            URI uri = new URI("https://api.eatstreet.com/publicapi/v1/restaurant/search?latitude=40.4310&longitude=-86.9149&method=both");
            httpGet.setURI(uri);
            addHeader(httpGet);
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void addHeader(HttpGet httpGet) {
        httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials("X-Access-Token",
                        "__API_EXPLORER_AUTH_KEY__"), null));
    }
}
```

This code is not producing any output at all which I believe is due to wrong authentication. I need help with getting data using the cURL command mentioned above in Android.

The output should look like as follows (JSON format):

```
{
  "address": {
    "apiKey": null,
    "streetAddress": null,
    "latitude": 40.431,
    "longitude": -86.9149,
    "city": null,
    "state": null,
    "zip": null,
    "aptNumber": null
  },
  "restaurants": [
    {
      "apiKey": "90fd4587554469b1144247b91fbcb2f349e8e58504b5a530",
      "deliveryMin": 7,
      "deliveryPrice": 3,
      "logoUrl": "https://eatstreet-static.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/images/restaurant_logos/egyptian-cafe-and-hooka-bar-29289_1426541949444.png",
      "name": "Egyptian Cafe and Hooka Bar",
      "streetAddress": "130 Northwestern Avenue",
      "city": "West Lafayette",
      "state": "IN",
      "zip": "47906",
      "foodTypes": [
        "Subs & Sandwiches",
        "Middle Eastern Food",
        "Mediterranean Food",
        "Hookah Bars",
        "Healthy Food"
      ],
      .
      .
      .
      {
      "apiKey": "90fd4587554469b1144247b91fbcb2f3720a4edae037dd96",
      "deliveryMin": 7,
      "deliveryPrice": 3,
      "logoUrl": "https://eatstreet-static.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/images/restaurant_logos/vienna-coffee-house-and-bakery-29290_1426542017375.png",
      "name": "Vienna Coffee House & Bakery",
      "streetAddress": "208 South Street",
      "city": "West Lafayette",
      "state": "IN",
      "zip": "47906",
      "foodTypes": [
        "Coffee & Tea",
        "Bakery"
      ],
      "phone": "(765) 743-4446",
      "latitude": 40.4239543,
      "longitude": -86.9079021,
      "minFreeDelivery": 0,
      "taxRate": 0.07,
      "acceptsCash": false,
      "acceptsCard": true,
      "offersPickup": true,
      "offersDelivery": true,
      "isTestRestaurant": false,
      "minWaitTime": 45,
      "maxWaitTime": 60,
      "open": true,
      "url": "https://eatstreet.com/lafayette-in/restaurants/vienna-coffee-house-and-bakery",
      "hours": {
        "Sunday": [
          "6:00 PM - 12:00 AM"
        ],
        "Wednesday": [
          "6:00 PM - 12:00 AM"
        ],
        "Tuesday": [
          "6:00 PM - 12:00 AM"
        ]
      },
      "timezone": "US/Eastern"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After your `addHeader(httpGet)`, you have to actually perform your `GET` operation using your previously defined `httpClient`:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
response.getEntity().getContent(); // do something with the response
// an example of continuing what you were trying to do
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

Also, your `addHeader(httpGet)` needs to be changed into this, to just pass the API key as header, and not as `UsernamePasswordCredentials`

```
 private static void addHeader(HttpGet httpGet) {
        httpGet.addHeader("X-Access-Token", "__API_EXPLORER_AUTH_KEY__");
 }
```